# How to hide the navigation bar on Android 7.1 on text entry field?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, navigationbar

I have the following code which hides the navigation bar:

```
int uiOptions = (int)(Forms.Context as Activity).Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;
uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;
(Forms.Context as Activity).Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
```

When I have an entry text field, where I enter text, the navigation bar shows back up.

I tried hiding it when the page appears with no luck.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkqEn.jpg)

Comment: it is xamarin forms android project in c#. here are the screen shots attached

Comment: I am not allowed to attach a image until i earn some points. it is such a mess

Comment: So you not need bottom buttons when focus comes to textbox?

Comment: yes that is correct. I am able to hide it by having the code above. But as soon as I tap on the text entry field, the key board pops up along with the navigation bar.

Comment: Bottom build in options seems fine until you strong reason to hide them. At the same time while writing something you could close apps, go to task bar, close keypad by pressing back button ...Etc those things you can do. If you hide those how will you close keypad?

Comment: it is our internal requirement as we do not want to provide user to access system menu or exit the app

Comment: Enter key closes the keyboard